# Use groupby() for plotting sales trend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by

I would like to understand how to use the groupby or a different function with this dataset:

```
Date_ren  Quant  Y      M
2002-03-14  32  2002    3
2002-02-24  31  2002    2
2002-02-21  28  2002    2
... ... ... ...
2011-04-02  1   2011    4
2013-02-25  1   2013    2
2019-05-02  1   2019    5
2012-01-03  1   2012    1
2014-05-01  1   2014    5
```

What I am trying to achieve is a good visualisation of this data by months through years. It is about the renewal of a product and the quantity sold through years in that particular months. Since I would need to compare how the trend changed through time, I was considering to plot them, grouping by months and considering the change through years in that particular time window.
I thought before splitting as I did above to use the following:

```
month = df.Date_ren.dt.to_period("M")  # new way to get the same
g = df.groupby(month)
```

or this:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
```

But the problem is to plot my data keeping only information about the year and the quantity sold in that year in a specific month and compare to the others.
So I should have or multiple individual plots which illustrates this trend or one single plot which compare by grouping by months the years. For example:

```
M=1 -> 2002 , 2003, 2004, .... , 2019
M=2 -> ....
M=3 ->
```

having the Quant on y-axis ( a frequency histogram).

Could you tell me how to consider the groupby() function in this particular case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try

```
df.groupby(['Y','M'])['Quant'].sum().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Following you comments I would try

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
g=df.groupby(['Y','M'])['Quant'].sum().unstack()
g.index.name = 'M'#g.index.name = 'Y'
g.plot(kind="bar")
```

Comment: thanks wwnde and sorry if I was not so clear in explained the problem. What I would like to do is just to see bar charts (maybe it would be better if multiple, for example for January I can plot all the years on the x-axis; then for February I do the same, ...) . I think in this particular case subplots should be better than one plot. But in Excel I could do it with stacked/unstacked clustered data (e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/302232/stacked-clustered-chart-in-excel)

Comment: See my edits. I am happy to help further if that is not what you are after